# Check whether any animation is playing or not

Tags: c#, animation, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am making **Windows Store App** in `VS2012 c#`.

Now I have 4 animation storyboard named "Jump", "Sit", "Roll", "Eat".

Now I have a `button click event` and want to check if any of these four animation is currently playing or not.

If no I will display Message using `MessageBox.show()` property.
And if yes, I will stop that current animation.

Thanking you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

you can check the ColackState of storyBoards and decide on basis of that.like this..

ClockState srt =    StryBrdSelectedSubjectlistGoOut.GetCurrentState();

if state for all the storyboard is stopped..show your message..hope it helps you..

Comment: it shoud work for you but it's ok --you can do one more thing that you can add eventhandler to the StryBrdSelectedSubjectlistGoOut completed event..like this..  StryBrdSelectedSubjectlistGoOut.Completed += StryBrdSelectedSubjectlistGoOut_Completed;

Comment: its showing error "StryBrdSelectedSubjectlistGoOut doesnt exsist in current context"

Comment: it  is your storyboardName bro..i think you have done the same mistake in my above answer..replace StryBrdSelectedSubjectlistGoOut  with your storyboard and then try my ans..